# How to remove <ul><li> tags when printing out Menu

Tags: routes, theming

Is there any way to remove HTML list tags when this function is called to access Main Menu?

This code is used in page.tpl.php in for a theme:

```
print theme(
  'links__system_main_menu',
  array(
    'links' => $main_menu,
    'attributes' => array('class' => array('topNavItem')),
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's pretty easy. But first I think you need to know what's going on here.

Drupal's `theme()` call above is going to look for a `theme_links__system_main_menu()` function/hook and failing that, will look for a `theme_links()` function/hook.

`theme_links()` is in drupal core in `includes/theme.inc` if you want to take a look at it, as that's "who" is putting the ULs and LIs in there.  **DONT** just edit that file/function/hook, but create your own in your theme.  So, to take them out, or to put *whatever* you want in, you just write your own theme function to do it, and then `theme()` above will call it for you.

Drupal's theme layer is described well here:  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7 and here: http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7 and should put you on the path to doing all that.